# Android volley.ParseError String cannot be converted to JSONArray

Tags: android, android-volley

I have this method on my Android volley activity:
[sendData](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2bCF7.png)

When I run it, I have this error:
[Error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5HBMw.png)

MySingleton object permits me to add a JsonArrayRequest to my requestQueue.

I understand that the error is located in the response. Nevertheless I can't figure out where my mistakes is...
Do you have any ideas? Thank you for your help

Comment: use postman to check the actual response.

Comment: while getting response you got error means your api call but getting error in reponse.

Comment: Do you mean that the problem is the response of the server? However the page show me an array of jsonObjects therefore I thought it was good.

Answer (score 0):

I used Postman... The problem was a comment in the beginning of my php file... Thank you so much !!